# filtering JSON data in swift

Tags: json, swift, api, parsing

I am trying to parse my JSON data and append only those objects into array which meets specified condition. At the moment I have commented out code which fetch all objects from the API and add them into array. However, I would like to limit it so that it only appends objects with "wger.de" value for "license_author" key.

However I am getting error on line:

```
if eachExercise["license_author"] == "wger.de"
```

**Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Any?' and 'String'**. 
However I still wants to keep it as Any object because I would like to fetch both strings and integers data from my API.

This is the code for my parseData() function:

```
func parseData() {

    fetchedExercise = []

    let urlPath = "https://wger.de/api/v2/exercise/?format=json&language=2&status=2"
    let url = URL(string: urlPath)!

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print("Error while parsing JSON")
        }
        else {

            do {
                if let data = data,
                    let fetchedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableLeaves) as? [String:Any],
                    let exercises = fetchedData["results"] as? [[String: Any]] {

                    // WORKING CODE
                    /*
                    for eachExercise in exercises
                    {

                        let name = eachExercise["name"] as! String
                        let description = eachExercise["description"] as! String

                        self.fetchedExercise.append(Exercise(name: name, description: description))

                    }
                    */

                    // TESTING
                    for eachExercise in exercises {
                        if eachExercise["license_author"] == "wger.de" {
                            let name = eachExercise["name"] as! String
                            let description = eachExercise["description"] as! String
                            let id = eachExercise["id"] as! Int

                            self.fetchedExercise.append(Exercise(name: name, description: description))
                        }
                    }


                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }
            catch {
                print("Error while parsing data.")
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Cast it to a `String`.

Comment: I tried it before and it did not work but then after few attempts I realized how it should be done. I confused myself before but it now works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `where` clause and optional downcast `Any` to `String`

```
for eachExercise in exercises where eachExercise["license_author"] as? String == "wger.de" { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need cast it to String.

```
if eachExercise["license_author"] as? String == "wger.de" {

}
```